# Validate XML Syntax Only in C#

Tags: c#, xml

There are a lot of tutorials that teach on how to validate XML against a schema. But now I want to validate XML syntax only, not against the schema. Meaning I just want to check whether the XML is well-form, that whether there are closing or opening tag that is not done properly.

Is there anyway I can do that in .Net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or if you're on .NET 3.5, you can use [`XElement.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.load.aspx).

> LINQ to XML's loading functionality is
>   built upon [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). Therefore, you
>   might catch any exceptions that are
>   thrown by the [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx)
>   overload methods and the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)
>   methods that read and parse the
>   document.

Comment: Use XDocument.Load() if you want to validate the declaration and processing instructions, too.

Answer (score 4):

Just open it in an XmlReader and read to the end.  If it makes it without throwing an exception, it's well formed.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a bit easier to use XmlDocument instead.

Comment: That would work, but it would also try to load the whole thing into memory and create a DOM.  Ugh. XmlReader will be _much_ faster.

Comment: Yes, that's entirely true.  XmlDocument is EASIER, not faster.  My thinking is that, since the goal is to validate the documents, it would be best if the validatOR were unamibiguously correct.  Since the process would likely wind up I/O-bound, I don't think the added expense would be a problem unless the files were exceptionally large.